# Display message when JavaScript function works

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to display a message when this function works :

```
  function testAPI() {
    FB.login(function(){
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'Hello World'});
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
```

My attempt was this and it didn't work :

```
  function testAPI() {
   FB.login(function(response){
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'Hello World'});
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'},{complete(response);});
  }
```

I'm getting this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Which function? the login of the call to `/feed`?

Comment: @Lix testAPI() function.

Comment: `FB.login(` is a function call not a wrapper you can't declare variable in it. Plus here it's to create a facebook function which isn't called anyway. `var facebook = ` is what is generating the error.

Comment: You avoid many problems if you'll properly indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Facebook API?if yes ,then Fb.login function may be having below signature

```
FB.login(parameter1,[parameter2,..],function(response){
    //do something with the response
});
```

you are declaring a new variable where you should be passing parameter an specify callback funtion.you should specify parameters required by the api and then in the callback function that you specify you could display whatever message you want.